# ActiveRecord Reputation System breaks other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a question and answer model for which I'm trying to add a functionality that will allow users to rate up or down a question.

I decided to work with [ActiveRecord Reputation System](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system) because it does exactly what I need and is very easy to implement. I'm quite new to ruby and rails development.

I realized though that as soon as I add the gem to my gemfile ( gem 'activerecord-reputation-system' ) and then run bundle install, all my other models break (can't create new records or update them).

At first I thought it might be a bug with ActiveRecord Reputation System or a conflicting gem, but then I also realized that all my records created in the database don't get an automatic created_at or updated_at value into them. They stay set to nil, even though I used scaffolding to create the models. That makes me think that this might be the reason why the ActiveRecord Reputation System gem breaks the functioning of the models. It might rely heavily on created_at and updated_at values. My other models don't suffer too much from the lack of that information.

I researched a bit and found that the created_at and updated_at set to nil happens to people who set `config.active_record.default_timezone` in their application.rb

I commented out those 2 lines in my application.rb to see if it would fix it:

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

I then added back the gem to my gemfile, but the same thing happens again.

In other words, I'm not sure if I have to fix the fact that records don't get the created_at and updated_at values automatically generated or if it could be a totally different issue going on here with ActiveRecord Reputation System.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in ActiveRecord Reputation System which was fixed in 3.0.1 (November 27, 2014). Update your gem.